# Automated comparison of XML files?

Tags: xml, comparison, automated-tests

I need a way of automating the comparison of XML files - any ideas/advise?

I am currently using XML spy and am looking into XMLDiff - this is currently a manual process of comparing the two files, getting the program to highlight the differences, and deciding which are the 'important' differences.

I would eventually like a way of automating this so that there isn't an enormous testing phase at the end of every update.

There are going to be a huge amount of comparisons to be done, and obviously the faster this can be done, the better (upholding the same level of quality of a manual check of course)....

Any ideas welcome,

Thanks.

Comment: What should the results of such a comparison be? A list of differences? A yes/no?

Comment: well, before you can automate it, you need to work out how to specify EXACTLY how to compare these files. Chances are, that not everything can be automatically automated.

Comment: I am hoping to achieve some sort of list of 'allowed' differences, such as UIDs, stuff like that, and if there are additional differences then for this to fail the test and give a list of the differences. Also I'm hoping to be able to ignore the order of the attributes - as you can do in most comparison tools

Comment: What kind of difference is allowed? Is it allowed that the structure of the XML differes or is it only allowed that the content differs?

Comment: What tools are you using to automate currently? Most test robots have a nicely integrated comparison feature, and those allow exactly the kinds of comparison rules you are looking for.